# Oracle Apex20.2 wizard when going back from form 2 to 1 the input fields in form 1 needs to retain their original values how to do this?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I’m fairly new to Apex but struggling with the wizard part.
I'm currently using apex 20.2

I have a wizard that works perfectly fine, passing item values from one form into another form item
I’m doing this with branches where in the behavior I set the value of the current form into the next one.
But somehow I cannot do it with the ‘previous’ button.
I would assume I could do the same, pas the item value from form 2 into the items from page 1
Then use that value as default item value?
But then I get an error saying there is no data.
Can someone point me in the good direction?

Thanks.

[when pressing the previous button the action is a redirect to page 12, i would need to pass that P10_NAME value into form item P12_NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV73i.png)

[In Page 12 a was assuming i would need to set a default to the item where i have passed the data in?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsxBA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a link, the target is generated at page rendering time. It does not pick up the current values in the form.
Instead what you could do is

- Change the button action to "Submit Page"
- Create a pl/sql page process to set the values (point: processing, condition when button pressed)
- Create a branch to redirect to the previous page (point: after processing, condition when button pressed)

The 2nd bullet is optional, you can also pass the values in the branch link. Since the branch is executed after processing the item values will be the new item values (and not the values at page rendering time you see in the link now)

Comment: i've done what you sayed, i gave the previous button the action 'submit page', made a 'previous branch' point = after processing, behavior = page or URL (redirect) then set items [(name)P12_NAME (value)&P10_NAME. ] (P12 is the page where i'm going to) but then i get an error ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512 any idea?

Comment: Run the app in debug mode and check in the debug messages what where the ORA-1403 is raised. That should get you in the right direction.

Comment: but i think the problem lies in the previous page (p12) where i probably set an incorrect default value i have it now set to type = item, item = P12_NAME

Comment: ok so it works now ? If you're happy with the answer please mark it as "answered"

Comment: oh no sorry, my comment was not clear, it was a question, is it ok that i set the default value's like that? cuz when i do it like this i get blank labels, not with the data that i have set from the previous page (i get no errors anymore)

Comment: oh waaw this is soo weird...
now, a day later I test it again without changing anything and now it works perfectly…
so thank you 

Comment: Graag gedaan :).